# how to calculate intermediate values within an arbitrary range

Tags: math, graphics, actionscript

I have to distribute on the screen N squares, and I have to scale them accordingly to the number of squares displayed on the screen.
Given that I have 100 squares on screen their scaling factor will be 4
if I have 900 squares on screen their scaling factor will be 1.1

How do I calculate an intermediate scaling factor between 101 and 899?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what function you use to calculate the scaling factor in function of the amount of squares.
But if there is a function that tells what scaling factor you need for a given amount of squares you can use integrals:

The intermediate value of the factor is the integral of the function from 101 and 899 divided by (899-101). If you're not familiar with the math, you can count up all the scaling factors and divide it bij the amount of terms in the sum.

example: for 100 = 4 and 900 = 1.1, the intermediate value is: (4+1.1)/2=2.55